# Re-using pipeable operators in RxJS

Tags: rxjs

I have two Subjects in an Angular component that leverage the same set of pipeable operators to provide typeahead search lookups for two different form fields. Example:

```
this.codeSearchResults$ = this.codeInput$
                               .pipe(
                                 untilDestroyed(this),
                                 distinctUntilChanged(),
                                 debounceTime(250),
                                 filter(value => value !== null),
                                 switchMap((value: string) => {
                                   const params: IUMLSConceptSearchParams = {
                                     ...TERMINOLOGY_SEARCH_PARAMS,
                                     sabs: this.sabs,
                                     term: value
                                   };

                                   return this.terminologyService.umlsConceptSearch(params);
                                 }),
                               );
```

The [definition for pipe](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/pipe) appears that it will accept an arbitrary number of functions, however providing the functions via spread

```
this.codeSearchResults$ = this.codeInput$.pipe(...operators);
```

isn't working as expected. How can I provide a single input source of functions for both Subjects to keep my code DRY?

## Edit

Following option #2 from Dan Kreiger's answer, my final code is as follows:

```
const operations = (context) => pipe(
      untilDestroyed(context),
      distinctUntilChanged(),
      debounceTime(250),
      filter(value => value !== null),
      switchMap(value => {
        const term: string = value as unknown as string;
        const params: IUMLSConceptSearchParams = {
          ...TERMINOLOGY_SEARCH_PARAMS,
          sabs: context.sabs,
          term,
        };

        return context.terminologyService.umlsConceptSearch(params) as IUMLSResult[];
      }),
    );

    this.codeSearchResults$ = this.codeInput$
                                  .pipe(
                                    tap(() => this.codeLookupLoading = true),
                                    operations(this),
                                    tap(() => this.codeLookupLoading = false),
                                  ) as Observable<IUMLSResult[]>;

    this.displaySearchResults$ = this.displayInput$
                                      .pipe(
                                        tap(() => this.displayLookupLoading = true),
                                        operations(this),
                                        tap(() => this.displayLookupLoading = false),
                                      ) as Observable<IUMLSResult[]>;
```

I needed to compose a couple of `tap()` functions that were unique per Subject and it works as expected.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here are 4 possible ways.

**1. Utility function that returns a list of operators**

If you want to reuse it between contexts, you can try making a function that accepts the `thisArg` and returns an array of operators.

Then you can spread the invoked function in the argument passed to `pipe`.

```
/**
 * @param {object} thisArg - context using the typeahead
 * @returns {OperatorFunction[]}
 * 
 * list of pipepable operators 
 * that can have a dynamic `this` context
 */
const typeAhead = thisArg => [
  untilDestroyed(thisArg),
  distinctUntilChanged(),
  debounceTime(250),
  filter(value => value !== null),
  switchMap((value: string) => {
    const params: IUMLSConceptSearchParams = {
      ...TERMINOLOGY_SEARCH_PARAMS,
      sabs: thisArg.sabs,
      term: value
    };

    return thisArg.terminologyService.umlsConceptSearch(params);
  })
]


// subject A
this.codeSearchResults$ = this.codeInput$
  .pipe(...typeAhead(this));

// subject B
this.articleSearchResults$ = this.articleInput$
  .pipe(...typeAhead(this));
```

**Note:** `terminologyService` and `sabs` would need to be present on the `this` context you pass to this function.

It looks like you are using these for components, so as long as `terminologyService` is being injected as a dependency and `sabs` is a static member of the component, it should work.

---

**2. Utility function that returns composed operators**

Alternatively, you could accomplish the same this by importing `pipe` from `rxjs` to chain the operators together.

```
import { pipe } from "rxjs";

// ... 

const typeAhead = (thisArg) =>
  pipe(
    untilDestroyed(thisArg),
    distinctUntilChanged(),
    debounceTime(250),
    filter((value) => value !== null),
    switchMap((value: string) => {
      const params: IUMLSConceptSearchParams = {
        ...TERMINOLOGY_SEARCH_PARAMS,
        sabs: thisArg.sabs,
        term: value
      };

      return thisArg.terminologyService.umlsConceptSearch(params);
    })
  );
```

In this case, you do not need to use the spread operator since the operators are composed together using `pipe`'s left-to-right function composition.

```
// subject A
this.codeSearchResults$ = this.codeInput$
  .pipe(typeAhead(this));

// subject B
this.articleSearchResults$ = this.articleInput$
  .pipe(typeAhead(this));
```

**Note:** `terminologyService` and `sabs` would need to be present on the `this` context you pass to this function.

---

**3. Service for custom operators**

You could make a reusable service for your custom piped operators. This would allow you to grab the `terminologyService` singleton from the reusable service itself.

However, it looks like `sabs` will still need to be available from whereever it is coming from.

If you choose to do this, make sure to declare `TerminologyService` in the top level providers - see example [here](https://medium.com/@MatheusCAS/injecting-a-service-into-another-service-in-angular-3b253df5c21)

Then you could inject it into your components.

```
import { TerminologyService } from "./terminologyService.service";
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { UntilDestroy, untilDestroyed } from '@ngneat/until-destroy';


@UntilDestroy()
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class PipedOperatorsService {
  constructor(private terminologyService: TerminologyService) {}

  typeAhead(thisComponent) {
    return pipe(
      untilDestroyed(thisComponent),
      distinctUntilChanged(),
      debounceTime(250),
      filter((value) => value !== null),
      switchMap((value: string) => {
        const params: IUMLSConceptSearchParams = {
          ...TERMINOLOGY_SEARCH_PARAMS,
          sabs: thisComponent.sabs,
          term: value
        };

        return this.terminologyService.umlsConceptSearch(params);
      })
    );
  }
}
```

Then you can use it in a component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { PipedOperatorsService } from "./pipedOperators.service";
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: "some-root",
  templateUrl: "./some.component.html",
})
export class SomeComponent implements OnInit {
  sabs = ['What', 'is', 'a', 'sab', '?', '']; 
  codeSearchResults$: Observable<string[]>;

  constructor(private pipedOperatorsService: PipedOperatorsService){}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.codeSearchResults$ = this.codeInput$.pipe(
      this.pipedOperatorsService.typeAhead(this)
    );
  }
}
```

**Note:** `sabs` would need to be present on the `this` context you pass to this function. I made a dummy one here.

---

**4. Service for custom operators (no `this` context)**

If you want to make this truly reusable and not have to worry about `this`, you can just compose the operators you need that do not require a `this` context.

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { pipe } from "rxjs";
import { debounceTime, distinctUntilChanged, filter } from 'rxjs/operators'


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class PipedOperatorsService {    
  get typeAhead() {
    return pipe(
      distinctUntilChanged(),
      debounceTime(250),
      filter((value) => value !== null),
    );
  }
}
```

Then be sure to add the specific operators you need in the component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { TerminologyService } from "./terminologyService.service";
import { PipedOperatorsService } from "./pipedOperators.service";
import { UntilDestroy, untilDestroyed } from '@ngneat/until-destroy';
import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';


@UntilDestroy()
@Component({
  selector: "some-root",
  templateUrl: "./some.component.html",
})
export class SomeComponent implements OnInit {
  sabs = ['What', 'is', 'a', 'sab', '?', '']; 
  codeSearchResults$: Observable<string[]>;

  constructor(private pipedOperatorsService: PipedOperatorsService, private terminologyService: TerminologyService){}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.codeSearchResults$ = this.codeInput$.pipe(
      untilDestroyed(this),
      this.pipedOperatorsService.typeAhead,
      switchMap((value: string) => {
        const params: IUMLSConceptSearchParams = {
          ...TERMINOLOGY_SEARCH_PARAMS,
          sabs: this.sabs,
          term: value
        };

        return this.terminologyService.umlsConceptSearch(params);
      })
    );
  }
}
```

**Note:** `sabs` would need to be present on the `this` context you pass to this function. I made a dummy one here.

It's been a while since I've used angular. I hope some of these examples are useful.

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed answer, I sincerely appreciate it! I had to do a little typecasting to get the compiler not to complain. I went with option 2 as I needed to compose a couple more operators. I'll add my final solution to my question.

Comment: I'm glad it helped. FYI I also just updated option 4 because I had forgotten to remove the `this` argument, in case you choose to make a service later for any custom piped operators: [see revision 6](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67679488/revisions)